# Adding different e-mail's in ASP.NET's web.config at run-time

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, web-config, appsettings

I'd like to know if there is an automated method to add e-mail settings to web.config.

There is already an e-mail set, and it's currently like this:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network host="0.0.0.0" port="25" userName="whatever@whatever.com.br" password="stackoverflow" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

So what I want is:

**1 -** How do I add a new e-mail in there set by textboxes in the webform ?
**2 -** How do I differentiate which one I want to gather at the time ? could you give me a simple C# example on how to get the configs in one of the two ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a requirement better suited to a database than the web configuration.  There are ways to add/update items in the web configuration if you feel like you must.  Look at the [WebConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx) class and it's associated methods.  Note that the id running the AppPool will need write access to the web.config file in order for this to work.  That in itself is a risk.

Comment: There is write access, and I do want to set it on the web.config for some reason, in fact, it's already set at the database, and I'm migrating this particular one to web.config. Thank you!

Comment: @MarceloRamires: don't forget that modifying the web.config will cause the application to restart, which may have repercussions for any other users on the website - I agree with tvanfosson here - if you're going to be chaning this on a frequent, ad-hoc basis, you're better off putting it in a database or similar.

Comment: @Zhaph - Ben Duguid Since it's just e-mail setup, it's goingn to be a first run thing. Then there's no issue..